# realmファイルの最適化処理（バキューム処理）は可能でしょうか

Tags: realm

SQLite などではデータやテーブルの増減があると不要な領域が発生するために、DBの最適化ができる機能（コマンド）があるようなのですが、Realm にも最適化する機能やコマンドはあるのでしょうか？

もしくは Realm の構造上、最適化する必要がないのでしょうか？
ご教授の程、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

ROS 3.6.0 以降であれば "vacuum" が可能だと以下リンク先に記載されていました。

[Vacuum Utility- Realm Sync Docs](https://docs.realm.io/sync/v/3.x/self-hosted/manage/server-side-file-growth#vacuum-utility)

> Realm stores its transactions within files on the server. Over time, these files can become fragmented as new transactions are too large to fit into previously allocated space in the file. When this happens, the file allocates more free disk space for the transaction and as a result a small amount of space may go unused in the original file. Over time, this unused space can add up and be wasteful as well as decrease performance. As a result, we offer a "vacuum" utility in ROS version 3.6.0 and newer. This utility removes the unused space and effectively compacts the transaction logs and state.

実行方法は以下の通りです。

> ```
> realm-vacuum <path-to-your-big-server-file>
> ```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。ご連絡が遅くなり大変申し訳ありませんでした。申し訳ないのですが、最適化は、C#でも可能でしょうか？

Comment: 私が回答したのはあくまで「realm でバキュームは可能か」の部分についてです。追加の疑問点については **新規の質問** として投稿してください。 / 参考: [質問の回答を受けて別の質問を追加したい時はどうしたら良い？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3345)

Comment: 承知いたしました。改めて質問させていただきます。